# Why I am getting corrupted size vs. prev_size while parsing a csv file in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am trying to iterate through a csv file (`|` as delimiter) line by line, grab a particular field in each line and print it. But I am getting `corrupted size vs. prev_size` while running the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("customer.tbl", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    while ((getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        char c_mktsegment[100] = {};
        int mkt_idx = 0;
        int count=0;

        while(*line != '\0'){
            if(*line == '|'){
                count++;
            }
                        
            else if (count==6){
                c_mktsegment[mkt_idx++] = *line;
            }

            else if (count>6){
                c_mktsegment[mkt_idx] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            //printf("%c", *line);
            line++;
        }
        printf("%s ", c_mktsegment);   
    }

    fclose(fp);
    //if (line)
    //    free(line);
}
```

Test Input:

```
1|Customer#000000001|IVhzIApeRb ot,c,E|15|25-989-741-2988|711.56|BUILDING|to the even|
2|Customer#000000002|XSTf4,NCwDVaWNe6tEgvwfmRchLXak|13|23-768-687-3665|121.65|AUTOMOBILE|l accounts|
```

I am targeting the values `BUILDING`, `AUTOMOBILE`

Output:

```
xVSJsLAGtn|4|14-128-190-5944|28Expected Expected Expected Expected Expected 
Expected Expected Expected Expected Expecorrupted size vs. prev_size
```

Also, if I enable `free(line)` end of the code block, I get `munmap` error. Can someone explain what's going wrong in these two cases?

Comment: You're changing `line` so you're calling `free()` with a different pointer than the one originally allocated with `malloc()` in `getline()`.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, it also means `getline` is being passed an incorrect `len` value as the incremented pointer means the buffer has effectively decreased in size for the next `getline` call. So `getline` is likely overflowing the buffer.

Comment: Ah, so should I keep a copy of the original one, and change the other one?

Comment: Thanks both of you. it works now, after I copy the original one, and change the new one. Makes sense. :)

Comment: Voting to close as "not reproducible" since the issue was fixed via comments, and this is a "debug my program" type of question that's unlikely to be of any service to future readers.